# Vertex Painting not showing up

Tags: shaders, vertex-paint, vertex-paint-mode

Hey all I am a bit of a blender noob and am trying to figure out why my painted vertex color is not showing up. I have created a Material and created a vertex color node in my shader graph with the col object that shows up as the default after painting but when exporting to unity or viewing in object mode I do not see my color, I do see it as colored if I render in blender. Any ideas ?

[image: Vertex Coloring]

Comment: If you want to see it in Solid mode, click that arrow to the right of the Wireframe/Solid/Material/Render buttons and change the Color option to Vertex.

Comment: That's pretty cool, I can see it in object mode now but it still isn't appearing when exporting it to an FBXand placing it in unity :/